# There should be a synonym between [premiere] and [adobe-premiere]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Tags [premiere](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/premiere) and [adobe-premiere](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-premiere) should be synonymized or merged, right? Presumably [premiere](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/premiere) would be the dominant tag since it is older.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, also premiere is a single word where as the company that makes premiere is really irrelevant.  Merged and synonym created.